In Yocto, how to use headers provided and copied by a kernel recipe?
Context
I am building a Xenomai4 patch for STM OpenST-Linux Yocto project .
The recipe looks like:
linux-stm32mp:
SUMMARY = "Xenomai4 Patch"
SECTION = "kernel"
LICENSE = "GPL-v2.0"

SRC_URI += "file://evl.patch"

KERNEL_DEFCONFIG = "defconfig"
KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS = ...

...

#HERE IS THE MAGIC <<==
do_install:append(){
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/kevl/evl
    cd ${S}/include/uapi/evl && find . -type f -name "*.h" -exec install -m 644 ${S}/include/uapi/evl/{} ${D}${includedir}/kevl/evl/{}
}

PACKAGES =+ " kevl-headers "

FILES:kevl-headers += "${includedir}/kevl/evl/*



Then I created another recipe to build and install libevl (Not included for simplicity).
And finally I am creating a recipe for an application that uses them:
TestApp.bb:
SUMMARY = "Xenomai4 App"
LICENSE = "MIT"
PR = "r1"

DEPENDS = "libevl libgpiod linux-stm32mp"

SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt main.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit cmake

FILES:${PN} += ${bindir}/TestApp

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DSTAGING_INCDIR=${STAGING_INCDIR}"


When building, it seems that the folder where kevl-headers files are installed does not match where TestApp attempt to take them:
TestApp STAGING_INCDIR=
./build/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa35-ostl-linux/testapp/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot/usr/include
kev-headers saves them at:
./build/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp2-ostl-linux/linux-stm32mp/6.1.82-stm32mp-r2-r0/packages-split/kevl-headers/usr/include
QUESTION
How to copy those headers files as demonstrated and access them from another recipe?
I am also open to suggestions of better approches.
ATTEMPTS

I tried to add include_directories with ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} that seems to work well, but then I get compilation conflicts between headers (time.h, size_t not existing, etc..)
I tried to copy the files from another recipe, this works partially and only 3-4 files are copied out of >10. Not sure why.
Attempting to copy the file from the kernel recipe that creates them seems a good approach, if it would work.


Your recipe for linux-stm32mp basically installs the header file onto the target image's include path ( rootfs ). Whereas you TestApp looks into the sysroot directory of that particular package TestApp and this is the right behavior. So rather copying the header files onto the target image, you need them inside the TestApp's sysroot path. And there's other way to do it too.

I would prefer to NOT ship the headers in the device. Could you elaborate on how to make the kernel sysroot path visible from within TestApp?

Having header files on TestApp's sysroot path doesn't mean they will be included into the target image. I'm not sure if (or how) you can make kernel sysroot path visible from TestApp.
